# Special functions of complex variables and parameters in GNU Scientific Library

Tags: c, complex-numbers, gsl

I want to calculate some integral numerically using GSL. It contains special function of complex variables and parameters. As an example Hypergeometric function 2F1(a,b,c,z). where a and b, are comlex number. GSL manual told that it can calculate Hypergeometric function from real variables and parameters. It is possible to calculate Hypergeometric function of complex variables and parameters?

Comment: What exactly you don't understand? Try to be more specific, post a code that you are tying to use without success. Reading the reference manual   I found: gsl_sf_hyperg_2F1_conj_e  which computes the Gauss hypergeomtric function (https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjABahUKEwi64r3OhI3JAhVGJw8KHfBCBzA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gnu.org%2Fs%2Fgsl%2Fmanual%2Fgsl-ref.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFrNYbBl0JVFb4yNLXnqgWWvQiU0Q&sig2=7WA5pXaDp1y-65wf32y5ng)

Comment: gsl_sf_hyperg_2F1_conj_e works if only b=a*. My calculation requires more general case where a!=b*

Comment: Does your code compile? I can't see the gsl header.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. I don't now what header I should use.

Comment: If is the first time that you use gsl try following the steps outlined in the manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Using-the-library.html#Using-the-library